# React native app is not detecting subscription is alive or not

Tags: react-native, in-app-purchase, ios13

We have developed one application where auto-renew subscription is there where user can subscribe and get content update every time.

**Flow of the application is below :**

- When app open at the time of launch screen we have put code to check the user is subscribed or not and the subscription stuff is check at our back-end side and we are passing purchase token from app side to back-end via an API. We have used [react-native-iap](https://github.com/dooboolab/react-native-iap#readme)
- Whole flow was working perfectly and app is able to detect the subscription but suddenly subscription was not able to detect by the app as I have upgrade my iOS from 12.4 to 13.0.
- After upgrade to iOS 13.0 app is not detecting the subscription that is been purchased before iOS upgradation process.
- Subscription duration is one month and after expiry of my old subscription now I have renew the same thing and this time app is able to detect the subscription.

I need help here that If someone has purchased the subscription before iOS 13.0 and if that user upgrade their iOS to 13.0 so every time they will suffer from the same thing that I described above ?

Comment: Have you able to rectify your issues? I'm still facing the same issue